# Logic error in reading only one line while utilizing files in java

Tags: java, file, import, logic

I have an assignment where I needed to create a program that has two files, the first one stores a set of strings, then the second one stores a copy of those strings but in all uppercase.

I successfully created the program however when my professor graded my assignment, he took points off since "There was a logic error in reading ONLY one line" from this line of code:

```
 String first_file_string = first_file_input.nextLine();
```

I'm not really sure what that means or how to fix it, any input or help would be much appreciated. Thank you for your time and consideration!

Here is my entire code and the line above is line 50, I'll put 3 *'s before and after the line.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class UppercaseFileConverter
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        // file creation and writing string of characters to the file
        System.out.print("Enter a file name to create the first file to read from: ");
        String file_one = keyboard.nextLine();
        PrintWriter outputFile_one = new PrintWriter(file_one);

    System.out.print("Enter a string of characters to store in the first file: ");
    String user_char = keyboard.nextLine();
    outputFile_one.println(user_char);
    outputFile_one.close();
    System.out.printf("\nThe file: %s has been generated.\n\n", file_one);

    System.out.print("Enter a file name to create the second file to write into: ");
    String file_two = keyboard.nextLine();
    PrintWriter outputFile_two = new PrintWriter(file_two);
    outputFile_two.close();
    System.out.printf("\nThe file: %s has been generated.\n", file_two);

    // Opening the first file
    System.out.print("\nEnter the first file name to read from: ");
    String first_file = keyboard.nextLine();

    // reading the first file
    File open_first = new File(first_file);
    if (!open_first.exists())
    {   // If file doesn't exist, program ends
        System.out.printf("ERROR: File, %s, cannot be found.\n", first_file);
        System.out.println();
        System.exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        // accessing contents of first file
        Scanner first_file_input = new Scanner(open_first);
        ***String first_file_string = first_file_input.nextLine();***

        // opening the second file
        System.out.print("\nEnter the second file name to write into: ");
        String second_file = keyboard.nextLine();

        // reading the second file
        File open_second = new File(second_file);
        if (!open_second.exists())
        {   // If file doesn't exist, program ends
            System.out.printf("ERROR: File, %s, cannot be found.\n", second_file);
            System.out.println();
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else
        {   // storing data into the second file
            String second_file_string = first_file_string.toUpperCase();
            FileWriter second_fwriter = new FileWriter(open_second, true);
            PrintWriter output_second = new PrintWriter(second_fwriter);
            output_second.println(second_file_string);
            output_second.close();
        }
        first_file_input.close();

        System.out.printf("\nThe contents of %s has been changed to uppercase and stored in %s.\n", file_one, file_two);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: you're reading a single line only, instead of the whole file

Comment: @mangusta Ok I see, would you possibly know a way to read the entire file? I'm new to java and my I haven't seen mentions of reading the entire file in the chapter we are currently on.

Comment: you just need to use a loop instead: `while((first_file_string=first_file_input.nextLine())!=null) { // write first_file_string into dest.file }`

Comment: @mangusta ok thank you so much